# php, глобальная область видимости

Tags: php

php 5.6

есть два файла:

### include.php

```
<?php

global $abc;

$abc = 3;

?>
```

### default.php

```
<?php

require_once 'http://server'.'/include.php';

echo $abc;

?>
```

при переходе на default.php, ошибка:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: abc in /data/www/html/test/default.php on line 5
```

Comment: `http://server`? Это что такое, зачем?

Comment: это url, так инклюдятся файлы, через url, не моё решение

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно подключаете файлы

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/include.php';
```

Пример, в случае если файлы в одной директории

Comment: Только нужно помнить что теоретически можно вставлять файлы и с других серверов тоже (см. allow_url_include), хотя я слабо представляю чтобы кому-то в трезвом уме это понадобилось

Comment: переношу ПО на другой сервер, в связи с этим править код не могу и должно работать как есть, на исходном сервере всё работает. текущий код в теме предоставил для примера, т.е. в ПО инклуд работает так в некоторых местах. allow_url_include - On

Comment: перетащил ПО на centos 6.9 и php 5.3
в этой среде подобной проблемы нет